# How to configure ebean server via java for Play!2.1.1

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Hi i'm having some problem with ebean and play configuration, seems like i can't get the ebean server recognize some classes in my project, i got

> [PersistenceException: The type [class model.mappe.NodoSemplice] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().]

where the class `model.mappe.NodoSemplice` is as such

> @Entity
>
> public class NodoSemplice extends NodoApprendimento {

and

> @Entity
>
> @Table(name="nodi_app")
>
> public abstract class NodoApprendimento extends Model{

the imports are correct and the ebeanserver configuration is as such

```
    ServerConfig def = new ServerConfig();
    def.setName("fluidefault");
    def.setDataSource(play.db.DB.getDataSource("fluiddefault"));

    //i package delle classi di sistema
    def.addPackage("model.contributi.*");
    def.addPackage("model.corpi.*");
    def.addPackage("model.mappe.*");
    def.addPackage("model.utenti.*");

    def.setDdlGenerate(true);    //per generare il DataDefinitionLanguage

    fluidefault = EbeanServerFactory.create(def);
```

the save was done trough via

```
 public void save(NodoApprendimento nodoApprendimento){
    nodoApprendimento.save(fluidefault.getName());
}
```

the server bootstrap is fine and also talking with it but still i got the persistence exception because the server can't recognize the class as an entity

Answer (score 0):

Check the following 3 points:

1. Try to annotate table (@table) with your concrete class `NodoSemplice`, not your abstract class `NodoApprendimento`.

   It makes more sense to bind your table with your concrete class.
2. Make sure a table named `nodi_app` exists in the database you connected to, and the schema is `public`.
3. In your `application.conf`, enable Ebean:

   ```
   ebean.default="models.*"
   ```